# How to handle Notification Touch event launch Activity using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have used **broadcast receiver** and **alarm manager**. Added the notification in particular date and time. The **notification** is showing fine. But when the user is ***touching the notificatio***n i want to ***launch myApplication***.

```
    Notification.Builder notification= new Notification.Builder(this);
    notification.setContentTitle("MY Title");
    notification.setContentText("Today you have scheduled for...");
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_launcher);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    notification.build();    

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 

    long futureInMillis =  dateSpecified.getTime(); //Some future date like 20 feb 2015 
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

NotificationPublisher class -BroadcastReciver

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

   }
}
```

I referred this [link](https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223).
I hope your understand what i'm trying to say. 
Please anybody help me. Thanks lot.

Comment: Please tell me if you need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when the user is touching the notification i want to launch
>   myApplication.

Because  `NotificationPublisher` BroadcastReceiver fire when notification is clicked so start Application from `onReceive` method of Receiver:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // start application here
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                         context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intentn = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intentn);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification); 
  }
```

Comment: I need to launch when the user is click the notification. But it is fired when the notification is received itself.

Comment: @PeriyasamyM: ok got your question see my updated answer

Comment: @PeriyasamyM: what problem getting and what you are passing in place of `HomeActivity.class`?

Comment: In place of HomeActivity i passing starting activity.

Comment: I have one more problem. The Notification bar right side notification time is showing wrongly. It is showing when the notification added time (The button click event time. it is not showing the notification occurrence time).
Thanks lot.